# Friend access in Scala

Tags: scala, friend

Consider

- a function `f` defined in package `p1`
- a package `p2` which does not contain `p1`
- a package `p3` which does not contain `p2` or `p1` nor it is contained by `p2` or `p1`.

In Scala, is it possible to declare that `f` is accessible from package `p2` but not from other packages (such as `p3`)?

Comment: Now that I think about it, somehow using package objects and implicits might be the way to go, importing some implicits into a package object (being in `p2`) and require it to be present when calling `f` (requiring it in `f` as argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I stretch your rules to their limits, it is possible. Though I'm not sure if that's intended or that you forgot a rule.

```
scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package p1 {
  object O { private[p1] def f = println("f") }

  package p2 {
    object O { def x = p1.O.f }
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package p3 {
  object O { def x = p1.O.f }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:2: error: method f in object O cannot be accessed in object p1.O
  object O { def x = p1.O.f }
                          ^
There were compilation errors!
```

If `p2` also can't be contained by `p1`, I don't think there's a way to guarantee that `f` can't be accessed from somewhere else. You *can* do some tricks with sealed traits and implicits.

```
package p2 {
  object O { def x = p1.O.f }
}

package object p2 {
  sealed trait Friend
  private[p2] implicit val p2Friend: Friend = new Friend {}
}

package p1 {
  object O { def f(implicit friend: p2.Friend) = println("f") }
}

package p3 {
  object O { def x = p1.O.f(null) }
}
```

But now as you can see you can still cheat in package `p3`. And without cheating `f` can't be accessed in `p1` itself, because `p1` also doesn't have the necessary implicit.

You can check in `f` whether or not `friend` is `null`. Then `p3` can't really use `f` but it will only fail at runtime, not at compile time. Although if someone is passing around `null` they can't really complain if things blow up at runtime.

Comment: Nice ! Thanks. The null parameter is interesting, this makes me wonder: is there no annotation that gives compiler error on passing null to a parameter ?

Comment: You could try some things with an `AnyVal`, since only `AnyRef` can be null. But I think it would still be possible to `null.asInstanceOf[p2.Friend]`.